# How to reclaim the space used by WSL2's ext4.vhdx

Tags: windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux, vhd, vhdx

After the release of the latest WSL2, I found it doesn't support GPU access, so I uninstalled the Ubuntu Distro and  WSL2,  but it leaves the following file behind which is over 7GB:

```
%LocalAppData%\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.Ubuntu20.04onWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState\ext4.vhdx
```

What is the proper way to remove this file and all relative components?

- I tried  to delete it directly, but I'm unsure whether it's the correct way since it doesn't solve the problem, as the file and its folder are still there:

  ```bsh
  wsl --shutdown

  diskpart
    select vdisk file="C:\WSL-Distros\…\ext4.vhdx"
    attach vdisk readonly
    compact vdisk
    detach vdisk
    exit
  ```

Answer (score 6):

If for example you installed Ubuntu from Windows Update is as simple as right click in the Start Menu Ubuntu tile -> Uninstall. If it still remains then open an elevated cmd and run `wsl.exe --unregister Ubuntu`